# How to execute some piece of jquery code only when the viewport is above 1000px in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, media-queries

I need to execute some jquery code here when the viewport is above 1000px and above only but I can't get it to work. Please someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    var width = $(window).innerWidth();

    if (window.location.pathname == '/') {
      if ($(window).innerWidth() > 1000 && y > 0) {
        $('#top').fadeIn();
        $('#header-space').fadeIn();
      } else {
        $('#top').fadeOut();
        $('#header-space').fadeOut();
      }
    } else {}
  });
});
```

Comment: This really looks like a job for media queries and CSS to be honest.

Comment: 100px? or 1000px?  Please update the question and title.

Comment: Sorry about the mistake. That should've been 1000px.

Comment: why are you writing scripts if we can solve the issue with simple css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont really need $(window).innerWidth() you can use plain js for it.

```
window.innerWidth
```

If you use Jquery it uses

```
$( window ).width();
```

https://api.jquery.com/width/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    var width = $(window).width();

    if (window.location.pathname == '/') {
      if (width > 1000 && y > 0) {
        $('#top').fadeIn();
        $('#header-space').fadeIn();
      } else {
        $('#top').fadeOut();
        $('#header-space').fadeOut();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I should have probably mentioned that purpose of the code is to show the menu referenced by the id #top. I added the code to execute only on the homepage which works. I don't want that behavior on viewports lower than 1000px. I have tried the code above but the menu still behaves the same as larger devices (above 1000px). I want the menu to remain unaffected by this code for this set resolution of less than 1000px. I'm doing this inside WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one this works for me..

```js
if($(window).width() > 1000){
   $('#top').fadeIn();
    $('#header-space').fadeIn();
}
else{
    $('#top').fadeOut();
    $('#header-space').fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: I am using this inside WordPress. I'm not sure whether the first line is required. I could be wrong.

Comment: That is jquery library file that is not required.if you have already invoked the jquery plugins

Comment: just replace the inner width into width as mentioned above it's work for me

Comment: Thank you! This is the final working piece and all the above answers were correct I just needed to tweak this a little.  `jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        var y = $(window).scrollTop();
        var width = $(window).innerWidth();

if(window.location.pathname == '/'){
if ( window.innerWidth > 1000) {
if( y > 0 ){
            $('#top').fadeIn();
            $('#header-space').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#top').fadeOut();
            $('#header-space').fadeOut();
        }

}}
 else {}
        
    });
});`